# Installing a completely new python [windows installer]

Tags: python

I am wondering why its not possible through the normal windows installer https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html to install a completely new python. I am using this installer in a script and when a python version is already installed the installer goes into "repair/update/uninstall" modus.

How is it possible to install a new python version in a customized folder?
Do I need to make a zip file from the isntall folder of the installer and provide this for further distribution?

Comment: Are you trying to install the same version? e.g. you already have 3.7 installed and you want to install another 3.7? You are correct that that won't work. If you want to separate Python environments you need to look into using Virtual Environments.

Comment: I want to install an indepenedent python version in  a special folder which is used for another product and only this.

Comment: but is it the same version? e.g. 3.7 and 3.7? If so then you need to use virtual environments: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/ . They use the same base interpreter but they keep your installed packages isolated so projects can't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Python installer for this. You must pack the files of the Python installation into your own installer. Be careful to include the `python37.dll` which may be placed in a system folder by the usual installer. For embedded Python it should be placed in the same folder as `python.exe`.

Comment: An embeddable zip might be better, since it is a lot smaller than the traditional installation.

Answer (score 0):

It is installed and added to path, the installer detects this and gives you the option to uninstall repair or update. You CANNOT install the same Python version twice (the different paths will conflict). You might end up messing up both installations if you try and hack it, and it's difficult to fix.

I don't know why you want multiple versions of the same Python version, but you should use Virtualenv or Venv. This will create a new Python installation that you can use as normal.

Virtualenv page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

You could also go for Anaconda for more control.

If you want to redistribute Python then you want to go for the embeddable zip files. Unzip and call.  You will get the same binaries as in the installer except it will not automatically added to path (making your installation safe).